# How to install Bower Programmatic API?

Tags: bower

I'm new to Bower.
Where I can find bower.js file?

```
var bower = require('bower');
```

Chrome says 'bower' not found.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node.js then you will need to run 'npm install bower' to get the bower package installed into your path.